# How to connect to bigCommerce API with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to an API, I'm a front end dev, not too familiar with server side & php. 
Would love your help.

This is the repository - https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php
I'm not using composer.

They say there -

> To use the API client in your PHP code, ensure that you can access
>   Bigcommerce\Api in your autoload path

I've been trying to figure out how to do that, but I just can't figure it out.

This is the code that i wrote -

```
 <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Alex
 * Date: 12/15/14
 * Time: 9:29 PM
 */
require '../bigcommerce.php';

//echo realpath('../bigcommerce/api/client');
use ֿֿBigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => '', //my store url
    'username'  => 'admin',
    'api_key'   => '' //my api key
));
$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();

if ($ping) echo $ping->format('H:i:s');

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}
?>
```

I use:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include  $class . '.php';
});
```

I'm sorry, but i'm finding it quite hard to explain the question. 
I need to include classes with autoload but it doesn't work, i have no idea why. 
It keeps telling me that failed to open stream.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Be sure to check your error log. Currently you are basically saying "it doesn't work" which doesn't make for such a good question.

Comment: You are right.
That's the thing, I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do :)
Was hoping for some help :)

Comment: First thing is to turn on error logging. You can put `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top of the page and it should output anything wrong. If that doesn't help, check the error log. By default on a *nix system with apache that is at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Other systems it would depend on your install. Other than that, what *is* happening? Are you getting any output or a blank page? Try adding some echo statements throughout the code to see how far you get if at all.

Comment: You should switch to the newer OAuth version of the API. You can find more information at developer.bigcommerce.com and here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I keep on getting "require(ֿֿBigcommerce\Api\Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Alex/Sites/Tranzilla/bigcommerce-api-php-master/tranzilla.php on line 13"

Comment: So does the file exist at `/Users/Alex/Sites/Tranzilla/bigcommerce-api-php-master/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php`? Since you are including  `../bigcommerce.php` I'm guessing you need to change your autoload to something like `../$class.php`. Also check permissions on the files. They will likely need to be chmod'ed at the very least to allow reading by the web server user.

Comment: Maybe you help me out with understanding how namespace works?
I read a lot of docs about it, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the composer method, you need to make sure you have a copy of bigcommerce.php on your server. That's the only file you need, you don't need to use autoload. Bigcommerce.php has all the classes in it already.
You can simply copy and paste it from here: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/bigcommerce.php

`require '../bigcommerce.php';` says that the bigcommerce file is stored one directory higher than your working directory. Is this so? If you are using it in your current directory, then it should be `require('./bigcommerce.php');`

Other than that, your code appears correct.

If that doesn't work, run command:
`chmod 0644 ./bigcommerce.php` on that file, to ensure correct permissions.